# Search a list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sorted list of floats where

```
l = [50.1234,50.1221,50.1200,51.5022,51.5021,51.4999,60,002,60.0023,60.0021]
```

I want to group all the floats based on parts per million differences. I have a function:

```
def ComputePPMError(t,e):
    return (((e- t) /t) * 1e6)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? In general I will have a list of objects that have a float property and I will want to do the same thing with a list of objects. For example:

```
class MZ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FileID = ""
        self.Mass = 0
        self.Intensity = 0
        self.RT = 0
        self.ScanNumber = 0
```

And now the list will be `list = [MZ objects]`

So the final results will be `dictionary of {average mass : list of mz objects}` In this example there should be three entries

The result is this:

```
l = [{mz1:list of mz Objects (3 entries)},{mz2:list of mz Objects (3 entries)},{mz3:list of mz Objects (3 entries)}
```

So in the above result, the final list contains a dict where the key is the mz values as averages and the values a list of the mz objects that were used to be grouped.

Comment: Have you looked @ `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your desired output?

Comment: Sure I want a dictionary of mz objects where the masses are grouped by parts per million differences as described. The solution below looks good

Comment: The problem with the solution below is that the interval is a part per million and that changes with the value. For example 10 ppm for 100 is .001 but 10 ppm for 1000 is .01 so the interval is dynamic

Comment: Is `interval_list` ready, or will it be calculated?

Comment: Can you explain how to use `ComputePPMError` and can you give the example output for the list `l`.

Comment: Sure I iterate through the list and compute error between two values. If the error is < some threshold then it is grouped otherwise a new 'entity group' is created and then that is compared again

Comment: I ask you again "Can you give the example output for the list `l` in your question?"

Comment: The output is a list of mz objects as I stated before. The input is a list of mz objects sorted by the 'mass' property. The output is a dictionary of mz objects where the key is the average mass and the value is a list of my objects. So the dictionary now contains keys and lists. I will send an example shorty. In essence the dictionary now contains the list of mz objects that are binned such that no other key is within a user defined ppm difference from any other

Comment: I understand the output format. But I cannot understand the MZ list content. You said interval is not constant. How will the interval change? Please give an example output for your example input float list. `l = [50.1234,50.1221,50.1200,51.5022,51.5021,51.4999,60,002,60.0023,60.0021]`. Example output should be something like `{50.121833333333335: [50.1234, 50.1221, 50.12], 51.5014: [51.5022, 51.5021, 51.4999], 60.002133333333326: [60.002, 60.0023, 60.0021]}`. If we solve this problem with floats, it is easy to modify the solution for MZ objects.

Comment: Do you want to group every 3 entries? Because you put 3 entries in every item of your example result. I mean, you use something like `{mz1:list of mz Objects (3 entries)}` for every item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for a sorted float list:

```
def interval_groups(l, interval):
    return [[item for item in l if item >= i and item < (i + interval)] for i in range(int(l[0]), int(l[-1])+1, interval)]

l = [50.1234, 50.1221, 50.1200, 51.5022, 51.5021, 51.4999, 60.002, 60.0023, 60.0021]

group_list = interval_groups(l, 1)
print(group_list)

group_dict = {sum(group)/len(group):group for group in group_list if group}
print(group_dict)
```

Output:

```
[[50.1234, 50.1221, 50.12], [51.5022, 51.5021, 51.4999], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [60.002, 60.0023, 60.0021]]
{50.121833333333335: [50.1234, 50.1221, 50.12], 51.5014: [51.5022, 51.5021, 51.4999], 60.002133333333326: [60.002, 60.0023, 60.0021]}
```

Here is a clearer version of `interval_groups` function:

```
def interval_groups(l, interval):
    """interval must be integer"""
    ret_list = []
    first_item_as_int = int(l[0])
    last_item_as_int = int(l[-1])
    for i in range(first_item_as_int, last_item_as_int + 1, interval):
        interval_list = [item for item in l if item >= i and item < (i + interval)]
        ret_list.append(interval_list)

    return ret_list
```

**EDIT:**

I deleted `start_value`and you can modify function for list MZ objects as:

```
def interval_groups(list_of_MZ, interval):
    return [[item for item in list_of_MZ if item.mass >= i and item.mass < (i + interval)] for i in range(int(list_of_MZ[0].mass), int(list_of_MZ[-1].mass)+1, interval)]
```